# vsftpd in a chrooted ubuntu environment on android

Tags: android, linux, ftp, chroot, vsftpd

I'm running a chrooted ubuntu 12 distro on my Android GalaxyTab and myTouch 4G phone. I have the LAMP stack running and everything is pretty smooth, but I can't get this simple vsftpd to work on either devices.

The only two lines I changed in /etc/vsftpd.conf:

```
local_enable = YES
write_enable = YES
```

From the client side I can ftp and login with my user/pass but it will not allow me to 'ls' or 'get' or 'put', any of these commands will result in the following error:

```
500 OOPS: socket
500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_result
Connection closed by remote host
```

I can however do 'mkdir' and 'rmdir' but other than that it will not allow me to manipulate any files. Any thoughts on why?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you checked the folders and files permissions to be the appropriate ones?

Comment: Yeah, yeah all my perms are set correctly. For now, I'm using an android ftp server instead, works for now...

Answer (score 0):

I search for it, and i really mixed up, so i decided to change vsftpd to sftp or something else, till i found a link about this bugg.

Then i found out this problem is solved in vsftpd version 3. So i search how to upgrade it and could found to add jessie repository my debian 7.3 and upgrade it so:

```
echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
aptitude update
aptitude upgrade vsftpd
echo "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
service vsftpd restart
```